# Save Relation between User and Entity in ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, form-authentication

I have an Exercise entity defined in my ASP.NET MVC4 Web Application.
I'm using the Form Authentication with the default AccountModels.cs class.

I have class which looks like

```
public class Exercise
    {

        private DateTime _DateCreated = DateTime.Now;
        private UserProfile _Teacher;
        public int Id{ get; set; }
        public string Question { get; set; }
        public int Anwser { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; }
        public int maxNbrOfAttempts { get; set; }
        public string Hints { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Quiz> Quizzes { get; set; }

        public DateTime Date
        {
            get { return _DateCreated; }
            set { _DateCreated = value; }
        }

        public UserProfile Author
        {
            get { return _Teacher; }
            set { _Teacher = value; }
        }

    }
```

Am I using the UserProfile correctly to link between an Exercise and a logged in user?
How can I get the current UserProfile in my controller?

Answer (score 0):

Change it like this:

```
public class Exercise
{
    public Exercise()
    {
        this.Date = DateTime.Now;
        this.Author = User.Identity.Name; //Write this line if you want to set
                                          //the currently logged in user as the Author
    public int Id{ get; set; }
    public string Question { get; set; }
    public int Anwser { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public int maxNbrOfAttempts { get; set; }
    public string Hints { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Quiz> Quizzes { get; set; }

    public virtual DateTime Date { get; set; }        
    public virtual UserProfile Author { get; set; }         
}
```